# Can I have form within a form? I am working on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

What can happen when a submit is done in nested forms?

Will it work if I write ??? -  my html file which is  angularjs like below:

```
    <form>

        <form> 
        </form>

        <form> 
        </form>

    </form>

</form>
```

Comment: no, forms within forms won't work

Comment: Nested forms are not valid, so you probably can't!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms

Comment: This, strictly speaking, is invalid HTML. It *is* doable though, in the sense that the page will display in some (probably broken) way. For Angular, you can use `ng-form`. It will handle partial validations (if that is what you want). I would suggest you tried to explain *why* do you want to do this.

Comment: You technically *can* have anything, the question is *if this gonna work or not*, in this case - it will *not*.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos, I am a beginner in angularjs, will refer to ng-form. Yes, I need partial validations. In my application user needs to select quantity for products of his/her choice which adds into Total Products selected.Then there is a creation of labels and attach it to each product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot nest forms in HTML, but in AngularJS we have [ng-form](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm) which should do what you're looking for.

```
<form name="parentForm">
   <div ng-form="childForm">
   </div> 
</form>
```

The `parentForm` will be submitted, and both `parentForm` and `childForm` will be accessible from the `$scope` associated with this view.